# Laravel lighthouse introspection query gives unauthenticated

Tags: laravel-lighthouse, graphiql

I'm using laravel `lighthouse graphql` and graphiql to use playground and view schemas.
I have enabled `lighthouse graphql introspection`, but the introspection query from graphiql gives `unauthenticated`. I need to make the introspection works with unauthentication too, since it will be enabled for dev environment only.